# SQL Syntax -- Group By ... Custom Aggregate Functionality?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I've got a situation like this:

**Table: FunTable**

```
ItemKey     ItemName     ItemPriceEffectiveDate    ItemPrice
11          ItemA        6/6/2009                  $500
12          ItemA        6/15/2009                 $550
13          ItemA        9/9/2009                  $450
14          ItemB        3/9/2009                  $150
15          ItemB        9/9/2009                  $350
```

**I need to do the following:**

```
Select
  ItemName as ItemDescription,
  (SELECT THE PRICE WITH THE LATEST EFFECTIVE DATE FROM TODAY THROUGH THE PAST)
FROM
  FunTable
GROUP BY
  ItemName
```

**The output should be this:**

```
ItemA $550
ItemB $150
```

So, effective dates for prices can range from 5 years ago through 5 years from now. I want to select the price that is effective either today or in the past (not in the future! it's not effective yet). It's got to be the "most recent" effective price.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (don't have your names, but you get the idea) ...

```
WITH A (Row, Price) AS
(
  SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Effective DESC) AS [RN],
         Price FROM Table2
  WHERE Effective <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.Row = 1
```

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, though I think the following may be a bit quicker:

Select ItemName, ItemPrice
from    FunTable f INNER JOIN (
Select  ItemKey, MAX(ItemPriceEffectiveDate) Date
From    FunTable
Where   ItemPriceEffectiveDate <= GetDate()
Group by ItemKey
) t
ON f.ItemKEY = t.ItemKey and f.ItemPriceEffectiveDate  = t.Date

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, i have no idea how to make it pretty

Answer (score 2):

```
select ft.ItemName,
       price
from   (select   ItemName,
                 Max(ItemPriceEffectiveDate) as MaxEff
        from     FunTable
        where    ItemPriceEffectiveDate <= GETDATE()
        group by ItemName) as d,
       FunTable as ft
where  d.MaxEff = ft.ItemPriceEffectiveDate;
```

Edit: Changed the query to actually work, assuming the price does not change more than once a day.

Comment: I'd say this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but my guess is that you mean need to use a sub-query, which could make it a very expensive query.

It may be easier to pull all the data in an use code to post-process it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

should work if you do

```
SELECT ItemName, MAX(ItemPriceEffectiveDate)
FROM FunTable
WHERE ItemPriceEffectiveDate < getDate()
GROUP BY ItemName
```

Comment: You'd want to get the price too. Which means you'd need to group by the price. And that won't give you what you need(unless the price never changes :)